# Node.js non www to www redirect does not working

Tags: node.js, redirect

I have referred to this:
https://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-forward-non-www-to-www-domain-name-and-vice-versa-in-node-js-express.html

And to other Stackoverflow questions, but I still get errors when doing what they said:

This code:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) == null ) res.redirect('http://www.' + req.headers.host + req.url, 301);
    else next();
});
```

Redirects me to www.localhost:8080 ...

I have tried other syntax but still not working:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) == null ) res.redirect('http://www.ride4you.co.il', 301);
    else next();
});
```

(It redirects too many time until Chrome is timedout).

My question is how to fix this, in order to redirect ANY kind of addresses in the web address bar to https://www.mydomain.co.il, 
for example: mydomain.com www.mydomain.co.il http://mydomain.co.il, I want all of them to point to the first I wrote.

Thanks.

Comment: so you are saying first code is working and second one doesn't

Comment: First code redirects me to www.localhost:8080 . I need it to redirect to my domain not localhost...

Comment: I tried second code and it works fine for me. But first code is better than second one. Put the first code and upload it to server and then navigate your domain.

Comment: Again, I have tried this, it redirect me to the address I mentioned above.

Comment: console.log(req.headers.host); // localhost:8080 and not ride4you.co.il why is it?

Answer (score 0):

Only allow the specific host you want through, and catch the unlikely case that it's a HTTP/1.0 without a host header.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if ( !req.headers.host || req.headers.host === 'www.mydomain.co.il' ) return next() 
    res.redirect('http://www.mydomain.co.il/', 301)
})
```

You can keep the users original request path in the new URL.

```
res.redirect('http://www.mydomain.co.il'+req.originalUrl, 301)
```

Comment: This page isn’t working
www.ride4you.co.il redirected you too many times.

Comment: BTW I am using routers like this: app.use('/rides', require('./routes/ridesServer'));

Comment: This is the code of app.js https://gist.github.com/razaviv/d0bdae716c17d6381eadaecde9169423

Comment: The port is sent as part of the host header, so `www.ride4you.co.il:8080` but if you are in a redirect loop with that code then something must else be responding on port 80?? Do you have something else in front of this app forwarding requests? or some other app running on port 80 doing redirects?